# Cannot output dict key & value in Google App Engine HTML template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary

I can't seem to get a Python `dict` to output its value in my HTML template.
The following code simply prints an empty `select` element.

**main.py:**

```
feeds = {'feed1' : 'http://test1.xml',
         'feed2' : 'http://test2.xml'}

template_values = {'movieFeeds': feeds}
        
self.response.out.write(template.render(temp, template_values))
```

**index.html:**

```
<select>
  {% for (key,value) in movieFeeds.items %}
  <option value="{{value}}">{{key}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Changing it to the code below does output the key:

```
for key in movieFeeds
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

### Edit:

**New code:**

```
{% for (key,value) in movieFeeds.items() %}
  <option value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 634, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/home/thomas/workspace/movieMashup/src/main.py", line 71, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(temp, template_values))
  File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 72, in render
    t = load(template_path, debug)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 100, in load
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader.py", line 80, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader.py", line 88, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 174, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 273, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 154, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 273, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 132, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 273, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 542, in do_for
    sequence = parser.compile_filter(bits[3])
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 338, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/__init__.py", line 558, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Could not parse the remainder: %s" % token[upto:]
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ()
```

Comment: Have you tried without the `()` around `key, value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `{% for key, value in data.items %}` with Django [0.96](http://django096docs.appspot.com/).
Try with this instead:

```
{% for item in movieFeeds.items %}
     <option value="{{ item.0 }}">{{ item.1 }}</option>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Came across an article saying that and spent last 20 minutes installing 1.1, up and running now. I'll mark this as answer as its a valid answer too. Thanks systempuntoout.

Answer (score 1):

As @systempuntoout indicated, this isn't supported in Django 0.96. You can [tell App Engine to use Django 1.2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) instead:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```